# pandas dataframe to find elements in one column by groups of another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, mode, group

I have a travel dataset that is as shown below.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4gk.png)

The question is For customers who have more than 1 booking, which is the most booked route (from_city to to_city)?

Do I have to merge to_city and from_city first and get a new column? If so then how?

In the next step do i have to "groupby" customers who have more than 1 booking if so then how do I do that?

In the last step do I have to use mode() to find the most used route from city to city.

Is this the correct way to do it or is there a better way?

Please help. Thankyou.

I tried but I am really not sure what I am doing. Looking for a little guidance step by step as to how best to solve.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].